# Remove duplicate entries in dropdown with ASP

Tags: asp-classic, active-directory

I have a piece of code which will show a list of service areas and, then, when you select a service area it will bring back a list of departments in the second dropdown box. I have the following code:

```
 <%@ Language="VBScript"%>
 <% response.Buffer = TRUE
 'Defines the variables and objects
 dim ADUser, RecordList, intOne, intTwo, intThree, companies, service_area, department, arrComp
 'Assigns the objComp and objDept variables to Scripting Dictionary objects
 %>
 <!--#include file="includes/functions.asp"-->
 <!--#include file="includes/display.asp"-->
 <!--#include file="includes/results.asp"-->
 <!--#include file="includes/timer.asp"-->
 <h1>Organisational Structure</h1>
 <div class="commandspace">
 <p class="infotext">The org structure can be viewed with or without staff, indented or left justified.</p>
 </div>
 <% 
 ADUser = "LDAP://RBCTHDC1/OU=Staff,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=internal"
 ' Make AD connection and run query
 Set objCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 objCon.provider ="ADsDSOObject"
 objCon.Properties("User ID") = "DOMAIN\username"
 objCon.Properties("Password") = "Password"
 objCon.Properties("Encrypt Password") = TRUE
 objCon.open "Active Directory Provider"
 Set objCom = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 Set objCom.ActiveConnection = objCon 
 objCom.CommandText ="select company FROM '"& ADUser &"' where company ='*'" 
 Set objRS = objCom.Execute 'Creates an object and runs the LDAP query
 companies = objRS.GetRows()
 set arrComp = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 for intOne = 0 to UBound(companies,2)
      if not arrComp.exists(companies(0, intOne)) then
      arrComp.add companies(0, intOne), companies(0, intOne)
      end if
 next 
 response.write "<form action='index.asp?View=Structure' method='POST'>"
 response.write "<select id='service_area' name='service_area' onChange='showTeams(this.value)'>"
 response.write "<option>Please Select</option>"
 for intTwo = 0 to arrComp.Count
      response.write "<option value='"& Server.URLEncode(arrComp.Item(intTwo)) &"'>" & arrComp.Item(intTwo) & "</option>"  & VBCrlF
 next
 response.write "</select>"   & VBCrlF
 response.write "<span class='structure-spacing'></span>"  & VBCrlF
 response.write "<select id='department' name='department'></select>"  & VBCrlF
 response.write "<span class='structure-spacing'></span>"  & VBCrlF
 response.write "<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit'>"  & VBCrlF
 response.write "</form>"  & VBCrlF
 if request.form("submit")="Submit" then
      service_area = request.form("service_area")
      department = request.form("department")
      if service_area = "Please Select" then 

      response.write "<p>Service area cannot be left empty</p>"

      end if

      if IsEmpty(department) then 

      response.write "<p>Department cannot be left empty</p>"

      end if
        objCom.CommandText ="select company, department, title, cn FROM '"& ADUser &"' where department = '" & department & "' ORDER BY department" 
 else
      objCom.CommandText ="select company, department, title, cn FROM '"& ADUser &"' where company ='*' ORDER BY department" 
 end if
 Set objRS = objCom.Execute 'Creates an object and runs the LDAP query
 RecordList = objRS.GetRows()
 response.write "<table>"  & VBCrlF
 response.write "<thead>"  & VBCrlF
 response.write "<tr>"  & VBCrlF
 response.write "<th>Service Area</th>"  & VBCrlF
 response.write "<th>Department</th>"  & VBCrlF
 response.write "<th>Job Title</th>"  & VBCrlF
 response.write "<th>Name</th>"  & VBCrlF
 response.write "</tr>"  & VBCrlF
 response.write "</thead>"  & VBCrlF
 response.write "<tbody>"  & VBCrlF
 for intThree = 0 to UBound(RecordList,2)
      response.write "<tr>"  & VBCrlF
      response.write "<td>" & RecordList(3, intThree) & "</td>"  & VBCrlF
      response.write "<td>" & RecordList(2, intThree) & "</td>"  & VBCrlF
      response.write "<td>" & RecordList(1, intThree) & "</td>"  & VBCrlF
      response.write "<td>" & RecordList(0, intThree) & "</td>"  & VBCrlF
      response.write "</tr>"  & VBCrlF
 next
 response.write "</tbody>"  & VBCrlF
 response.write "</table>"  & VBCrlF
 objRS.Close
 objCon.Close
 Set objCon = Nothing
 Set objCom = Nothing
 %>
```

I can't find a way of removing duplicate entries. Using a Scripting Dictionary, I am getting an empty drop down box. Instead of returning a list of service area, it doesn't return anything - just an empty option value

Comment: You could either SELECT DISTINCT within your SQL or create a temporary company or department value within your loop statements at the bottom. Then at the top of the loop compare the current company or department to this temporary one. If they are the same (meaning 2 duplicate entries due to your ORDER BY) then do not response.write the results of that row of the recordset

Comment: I have solved it now